# C++ Pimpl idiom, class templates, and void template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to use the pImpl idiom with class templates and am encountering a problem when the template parameter is `void`. Here's my latest contrived example:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T> class Foo {
    class                 Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
public:
    Foo()
        : pImpl{new Impl()} {
    }
    void set(T value) {
        pImpl->set(value);
    }
    T get() {
        return pImpl->get();
    }
};

template<typename T> class Foo<T>::Impl {
    T value;
public:
    void set(T value) {
        this->value = value; // among other things
    }
    T get() {
        return value; // among other things
    }
};

template<> class Foo<void> {
    class                 Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
public:
    void set() {
        pImpl->set();
    }
    void get() {
        pImpl->get();
    }
};

class Foo<void>::Impl {
public:
    void set() {
        // do useful stuff
    }
    void get() {
        // do useful stuff
    }
};
```

Compiling the above results in the following:

```
$ g++ -dumpversion
4.8.5
void_int_template.cpp: In member function ‘void Foo<void>::set()’:
void_int_template.cpp:34:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Foo<void>::Impl’
         pImpl->set();
              ^
void_int_template.cpp:30:27: error: forward declaration of ‘class Foo<void>::Impl’
     class                 Impl;
                           ^
void_int_template.cpp: In member function ‘void Foo<void>::get()’:
void_int_template.cpp:37:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Foo<void>::Impl’
         pImpl->get();
              ^
void_int_template.cpp:30:27: error: forward declaration of ‘class Foo<void>::Impl’
     class                 Impl;
                           ^
```

How can I specialize the class templates to accommodate a `void` template parameter?

Comment: A class template specialization isn't a "tweak" on the original template - it's a separate class in its own right, having nothing but the name in common with the original template. It doesn't somehow inherit its members, as you seem to assume. The immediate problem you observe is that `template<> class Foo<void>::Impl {...}` causes an implicit instantiation of `Foo<void>`, and then you provide an explicit specialization for the same.  This makes the program ill-formed (by way of ODR violation, I think but am not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full specialization provides an alternate definition, meaning that you have to redefine everything.

```
template<> class Foo<void> {
    class                 Impl;
    std::shared_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
public:
    Foo();
    void set();
    void get();
};

class Foo<void>::Impl {
public:
    void set() {
    }
    void get() {
    }
};

// these need to be inline iff it's in your header file
/* inline */ Foo<void>::Foo() : pImpl(new Impl) {}
/* inline */ void Foo<void>::set() { pImpl->set(); }
/* inline */ void Foo<void>::get() { pImpl->get(); }
```

Comment: That seems like it should work but doesn't appear to. I modified my example according to your advice and now get a "forward declaration" error in the template class `Foo<void>`. See the new example.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson That's why I have the member functions defined out of class in my answer...

Comment: I downvoted because this seemed wrong, but the more I understand the question, the more right this answer is.  Can you clarify it a bit? (That the problem is that `Foo<void>::set` gets instantiated because it doesn't depend on a template type, therefore you need to defer method instantiation)

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! Moving the declarations into a header-file and the `Impl` implementations into a source-file solved the problem (which is how the `pImpl` idiom should be used anyway). It's slightly dismaying that this physical difference is necessary when the logical structure is the same. Oh well... :-)